# Create a CMS plugin that can use the Google Analytics API on any domain name?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-api

I'm making a plugin to a CMS, the plugin is a easy simple view of Google Analytics, with graphs etc.
I'm using the Embed API, https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/

But the problem is, that now that I've created the plugin, it doesn't work on other domains than mine.

If I remove my domain from the API Manager/Google Developers Console, under Restrictions, it doesn't work at all

How can I do so it's working on all domains?

Comment: Some plugins require that you obtain your own API key to use the plugin.   Would that be an option?   Get your users to use their own API key?

Comment: Hmm, well it would be a solution. But some of my users isn't that good with technology. But since I'm developing the plugin and installing it, I could do it for them. But I'm thinking of releasing the plugin to the public , and then I can't do it for them

Comment: Not ideal, but there is precedent for it.   I've used oauth login plugins for Google and Facebook that require you to obtain a developer key and put your key into the preferences section for the plugin.

Comment: Hmmm..
Also for clients ?

Comment: To make the plugin work on users site, users should create their own API key for their own site at API Manager/Google Developers Console. Then setup your plugin with their own API key. Correct?